# How to show error page when exception happens in JSF beforephase?

Tags: redirect, error-handling, jsf-2

The JSF2 specs are pretty clear in that exceptions thrown in a beforephase method are swallowed by the container. All I see is a small message in the console log.

However, I threw an exception in the beforephase because data could not be retrieved, and of course I want to show an error page with some more information. Unfortunately I'm unable to work it out.

Throwing the Exception from anywhere else works fine, my error page and errorhandler are setup fine to catch these errors, but I can't pick them up from any beforephase method (fortunately I only have a few).

Any hints how this can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: Let's take a step back. Why are you doing expensive business job in a phaselistener? What's the functional requirement for this all? There are likely better places to fulfill the job.

Comment: Well long long time ago we didn't have view scope, so we put our bean on session, and since we have to initialise a few bits when a request is not a postback, it's done in the beforephase. It seems now that some data retention across the entire session is wanted, so moving to viewscope isn't an option anymore either.